# Js regex for password validation match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regex in conjunction with abide Foundation for validating a password:

```
<form id="setPassword" action="{{ url('changePasswordWithoutToken') }}" method="POST" class="account setPassword" data-abide="ajax" novalidate="novalidate">
{{ csrfToken() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ data.token }}"/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns"><p>{{ 'PLEASECHOOSEAPASSWORD'|trans }}</p></div>
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label class="password" for="setPasswordField">
                <input type="password" id="setPasswordField" name="setPasswordField"  pattern="passwordAdditional" required placeholder="{{ 'ACCOUNTLOGINLABELPASSWORD'|trans }}" />
                <small class="error">{{ 'PASSWORDSHOULDCONTAIN'|trans }}</small>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label class="confirmPassword" for="confirmSetPassword">
                <input type="password" id="confirmSetPassword"  name="confirmSetPassword" data-equalto="setPasswordField" required placeholder="{{ 'CONFIRMPASSWORD'|trans }}" />
                <small class="error">{{ 'ACCOUNTREGISTRATIONERRORDIFFERENTPASSWORDS'|trans }}</small>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-5 large-4 columns">
            <button type="submit" class="button" id="setPasswordBtn">{{ 'SAVECHANGES'|trans }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

patterns: {
    passwordAdditional: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_\W\S]).{8,}/
}

It deosn't seem to pick up the symbol, when I enter a new password without a symbol the validation message disappears. It shouldn't as I haven't inserted any symbol inside the new password. Is my regex wrong?

Comment: Without password validation requirements, a password validation regex is both valid and invalid equally at the same time.

Comment: `[_\W\S]` matches literally everything - i guess you are looking for something like `[^A-Za-z0-9\s]`

Comment: Something like `^(?=[a-zA-Z\d_\W\S]).{8,}$` ?

Comment: ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,} I thought this one would work until I have tried the "£" sign in and it didnt validate

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dG9xL8/1 - I hope this helps

Comment: http://html5pattern.com/Passwords Has some default password patterns that I always used as a base :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, there are 2 mistakes you made:

`(?=.[a-z])` is looking ahead for a single character followed by a lowercase letter, but your intention is to find a lowercase letter in the string, so the `.` should be modified by `*` (0 or more times)

`(?=.[_\W\S])` is looking ahead for a single character followed by either underscore or a non-word or a non-space, which is litereally everything. This seems to be your check for a symbol, but it will always match (if there are at least 2 characters). I would use a negation to achieve this, like `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])`

This leads to the following regex

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]).{8,}$/
```

You can look at https://regex101.com/r/dG9xL8/1 for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/
```

It needs at least 1 upper case & lower case letter, a digit and a symbol (among `#?!@$%^&*-`).